# How can I turn off combat signals?

Tags: the-witcher

I started the game on Normal difficulty.

The manual says:

Easy – perfect for novice players (not only of The Witcher). At this level, game 
elements are introduced gradually. Opponents cause less damage and Geralt 
gains experience more quickly. **During combat, additional signals help you click 
your way through fluid attack sequences.**

Medium – recommended for experienced gamers who are new to The Witcher. 
**Attack sequences are not assisted** and click intervals are shorter. Opponents 
have standard attributes and Geralt gains experience at a standard rate.

Hard – for highly experienced players. Monsters and other opponents 
are significantly more powerful, click intervals are brief, and Geralt gains 
experience more slowly. At this level, selected opponents cannot be defeated 
without resorting to alchemy.

But I still get those red sword icons on my cursor to show me when to attack. How do I turn that off? :/

Comment: Just to double check: you mean The Witcher and not it's sequel, correct?

Comment: Yeah, The Witcher 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaming sword icon indicates the end of an attack, so you can chain the next one.

It appears only on easy and medium settings.

From the [Wikia](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_controls#Attacking):

> On hard, you only see a blue streak where your sword has just travelled and hear a faint "whooshing" sound to alert you to the timing of your attacks.

Comment: So what are these signals the manual speaks of that is only on easy?

Comment: @Zeno - On easy, it not only displays icons, but also tells you when to land the next blow in the sequence, saying things like "now!" or "too fast!".

Comment: I still get those messages like "too fast" on Normal. :/

Comment: did you start the game on easy and tried to switch to medium via the decompile hack?

Comment: Nope, always been on Normal.

Comment: hmm, well, then, I am clearly misinformed.

Comment: @Zeno there's a specific option to enable/disable these messages.

Comment: But I don't know about a way to disable the cursor (if you wish to).

Comment: Actually, the streaking indicator is orange.